# How do I create multiple page while active a theme

Tags: pages, page-template

I want create 5 pages when user active my theme. I found a code from [wpcanyon](http://wpcanyon.com/tipsandtricks/automatically-create-a-page-on-theme-activation/) which can create one page only. From this code how do I create 5 pages without repeat it 5 times.

```
if (isset($_GET['activated']) && is_admin()){

    $new_page_title = 'This is the page title';
    $new_page_content = 'This is the page content';
    $new_page_template = ''; //ex. template-custom.php. Leave blank if you don't want a custom page template.

    //don't change the code bellow, unless you know what you're doing

    $page_check = get_page_by_title($new_page_title);
    $new_page = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_title' => $new_page_title,
        'post_content' => $new_page_content,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
    );
    if(!isset($page_check->ID)){
        $new_page_id = wp_insert_post($new_page);
        if(!empty($new_page_template)){
            update_post_meta($new_page_id, '_wp_page_template', $new_page_template);
        }
    }

}
```

Let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ehm, just repeat the page creation code several times, providing different content and such. Is there any issue with that?..

Comment: No issue with it. But possible to make it more simple :)

Comment: @haha well, you can create separate function for creating page and call it five times... In the end creating page is just creating page. :) There is no API way to create bunch of pages at once or anything.

Comment: Yeah! make a function

Comment: Just create an array and loop through it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (isset($_GET['activated']) && is_admin()){
    add_action('init', 'create_initial_pages');
}

function create_initial_pages() {
    $pages = array(
        'page1' => 'Page 1',
        'page2' => 'Page 2',
        'page3' => 'Page 3',
        'page4' => 'Page 4',
        'page5' => 'Page 5'
    );
    foreach($pages as $key => $value) {
        $id = get_page_by_title($value);
        $page = array(
            'post_type'   => 'page',
            'post_title'  => $value,
            'post_name'   => $key,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author' => 1,
            'post_parent' => ''
        );
        if (!isset($id)) wp_insert_post($page);
    };
}
```